# Vue - manage custom v-model in child component when parent doesn't pass the prop

Tags: vue.js, parent-child, v-model

I'm trying to implement a custom v-model for a child component.
I'd like to make the v-model not required.

Here's the configuration of the child component with the custom v-model:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editing: false,
    };
  },

  model: {
    prop: "media",
    event: "changed-media",
  },

  props: {
    media: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => null,
    },
  },

  methods: {
    update(selection) {
      this.$emit("changed-media", selection);
    },
  },

};
```

As you can see, the prop with the custom v-model is called `media`. When my child component needs to update the `media` prop, it can call the `update(selection)` method, where it emits the event to the parent so it can change the value.

This works great when the parent passes the v-model to the child, however when this is not the case, the changes are not applied because of course the parent does not pass the updated value.

What would be a smart way to solve this?

Comment: I believe the way to do that would be to create a local data variable where that you clone from the media model during mounted hook and then use this local data variable in your templates. You'll then need to watch the media prop as well for changes coming from your parent and update the local data variable on change. Maybe post your template code as well so we can see how you are using `update()` in it.